# Como hacer para que el número 1 represente 1 link y que el número 2 represente otro link?

Tags: javascript, html

Cómo podria hacer para que cuándo yo le de al botón y me salte la advertencia pero en vez que me salte el número 1 o 2 me salga el link ej: 
    Link: "http://youtube.com"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script language="javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ejemplo2() {
var aleatorio = Math.round(Math.random()*10);
alert("Link:"+aleatorio);}
</script>
<form>
<input onclick="ejemplo2()" type="button" value="Ejemplo 2"></form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: osea que quieres que en vez de esto `Link:2` salga esto: `youtube.com` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer pero no podras poner un link dentro de un alert, lo que se me ocurre es que cuando presiones el ok del `alert()` lo redirijas a donde quieres ejemplo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script language="javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function ejemplo2() {
            var aleatorio = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
            if (window.confirm('mensaje al usuario que al presionar ok se redirigira a otra pagina')) {
                window.location.href = 'https://www.youtube.com/';
            };        
        }
        </script>
        <form>
            <input onclick="ejemplo2()" type="button" value="Ejemplo 2"></form>
        </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: pero estas deacuerdo que esto no sigue el camino, que el OP pregunta sobre el número 1 o el número 2

Comment: si solo que no entendi si quiere dirigirse al link o solo mostrarlo o si tendra 10 sitios casa uno asignado a un numero aleatorio y depende del numero lo redirija

Comment: Está redirigiendo indiscriminadamente a un mismo sitio siempre. Coincido con @shadow, no se está respondiendo la pregunta ni haciendo uso del valor "aleatorio".

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes mostrar un mensaje al usuario pidiendo confirmación para ser redirigido a un sitio dependiendo del valor obtenido y almacenado en "aleatorio". Si no deseas pedir confirmación, solo debes borrar el confirm y ejecutar el código directamente. Por otro lado, el mensaje solo se mostrara cuando haya coincidencia con los valores asignados en el `switch`, en este caso solo acepta 2 valores (1 y 2). También utilizo `parseInt()` para asegurarme que la comparación se realice contra un numero entero. A modo de demostración y verificación imprimo el valor de aleatorio por consola, como para entender que es lo que esta pasando. Saludos!

```js
function ejemplo2()
{
  let aleatorio = parseInt(Math.round(Math.random()*10));
  console.log("Aleatorio: "+aleatorio );
  let link = "";
  switch(aleatorio) {
      case 1:
          link = "http://www.youtube.com";
          break;
      case 2:
          link = "http://www.Link2.com";
          break;

  }
  if(link !== ""){
    let pregunta = confirm("Presione ok para ser redirigido a "+link);
    if (pregunta){
      window.location= link;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="ejemplo2()">Ejemplo 2</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a los que respondieron, el usuario Fran Islas puso lo que queria, muchas gracias!

Comment: @Pablosqui en vez de dar las gracias, pulsa en el check verde bajo la puntuacion de la respuesta para aceptarla como válida. Ambos ganais reputacion. Un saludo